# Is this mold in the walls or something else?

Tags: walls, mold

We are remediating visible mold in certain areas of the house. This weekend  I took photos in side the walls and into the attic. Does these photos look like mold or something else? Some of the dark areas in the photos could be shadow.

[Video: in the wall](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Id9y7xGk5Uo)
[image: Attic from ceiling below]
[image: Laundry room wall]
[image: Attic Insulation]
[image: Attic though ceiling below]
[image: Inside wall, a horizontal structural piece]
[image: Close up of previous photo]
[image: Note the green specs, inside wall (white dust is probably from drilling the wall]
[image: Inside wall on sheetrock]

Answer (score 1):

In the San Fernando valley 30 miles north of Los 
Angeles a family member died. Leaving the spouse 
alone. Mysteriously 7 years later the remaining 
spouse died. When the coroner came, he thought 
their was a death their in the past. Records confirmed 
what he thought. There was a lot of mold between
the studs, and behind the walls. 
My point is, if you don't know find out quickly. It can be concluded with a test of the air over a period of hours?!
Don't wait. Come to a conclusion professionally.
Painted for 7 years. Dealt with minor stuff, maybe 
10 square inches in the past. Did train with a 
firm that taught me what to look for when bidding
for new work. 
I would contact my insurance company and go
from there. Get informed quickly.